# Preloader div doesn't load before most of the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a pretty heavy HTML/jQuery page. Timeline shows an average loading time of 1.5s, so I have decided to show a preloader.

I implement it this way :

HTML just after the `<body>`:

```
<div id="loader-wrapper">
    <div id="loader"></div>
    <div class="loader-section section-left"></div>
    <div class="loader-section section-right"></div>
</div>
```

And then at the begining of my js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').addClass('loaded');
    $('h1').css('color','#74777b');
});
```

The "loaded" class allows me to trigger the disappearing of the loader as loading of the page is done.

The problem here is that before my loader covers the screen, I can see for approx half a second the html frame of the website starting to build.
How can I make sure that the first thing displayed will be my loader div ?

(sorry but I can't give link or jsfiddle of the project)

**UPDATE** : To be more specific, the loader works perfectly, but it doesn't start first. Let's say that the total loading time is 2s, the loader will only load on the last 1s. The browser is always building the DOM before displaying the loader.

**UPDATE2** : I have tried with a loader without animation, just made of simple div covering the whole screen and with "Loading" as text and I still have the same issue, here is a screen capture of what I can see before the loader appears('please note that the body pic is quite heavy as it is made of 4 layers of different colors stacked through a z-index setting')
[image]

Comment: You can add yo your css `body{opacity:1}` and `body.loaded{opacity:1;}`

Comment: I guess you meant  body{opacity:0} .... in this case the loader doesn't even show. I have tried to do the opacity trick on the container after the loader.... the problem is still the same, I have an empty screen for 0.5s before the loader displays.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My mistake.

Comment: A live example would make things easier for us, is it possible for you to paste a link ? What kind of preloader is it (gif, css anim ?) ?

Comment: impossible to paste a link unfortunately. It is a css anim

Comment: Can you try without CSS anim ? Just using text : <div id="loader">Loading...</div> ? What you describe makes me think you are waiting for full css to load and show your anim up.

Comment: Just another question : how many CSS calls (<link />) do you have in this page ? How many JS calls  (<script src="whatever.js" /> ?

Comment: 8 css files and 13 js

Comment: Hmmm ok :) So, first of all, you could concatene / minify all CSS and JS in your production environnement (it would reduce file size and network requests, from 21 to 2 for CSS and JS files).

Comment: Then, try what I suggested above : remove CSS (styles and anim) from your loader, and just put text in it, and share the result.

Comment: it's already done, most of them are minified libraries : jquery, jspanel, tinymce

Comment: Ok but concatenation will reduce network requests : loading 1 file instead of 13 will make things go faster.

Comment: I can try, but what I manage to see before the loader starts is the frames with their css style on, but the content inside is not yet displayed. So I guess it renders all the div elements of the page before rendering the loader

Comment: So you tried just putting text in it / removing CSS on it ? Browser reads HTML from top to bottom. If your loader is in top of it (just after <body> opening), it should be rendered before everything. If it doesn't, something else (CSS/JS) is delaying its rendering.

Comment: I've just tried and I still get the same thing, gonna try to make a screen capture

Comment: That would be better, but I guess you will have a good answer when you gonna paste a link to a live demo / the project. **We only can suggest things, but as there's too many element to take into consideration we can't give you a proper answer.**

Comment: update show the printscreen. I know it's not easy cause there is no live demo.... just trying to see if anyone got a good idea :)

Comment: You didn't post enough of your code for us to really be able to help

Comment: The sreenshot told us that : part of CSS is loaded (which part ? before or after css related to the loader?), part of HTML is loaded (or maybe totally, I can't see). So I think "Loading..." text is showing, but  I guess the header is hiding it (position fixed or absolute maybe). Then, when the css file containing loader style is loaded (as you load 8 css files), it shows up.

Comment: I've just moved the css file related to the loader on top position, same issue. The loader css instructions are at the very begining of the file. I also  put the loader inside the header, at its begining, same issue.

Answer (score 2):

**So, what is the root cause of this issue?** That's that JavaScript is single-threaded. There's a main thread that's continuously running, and it is simply taking a long time to complete the rendering. This can cause freezing of the browser and squirrelly loading divs.

**With asynchronous calls, JavaScript can mimic multithreading** and address the root cause. The main thread keeps spinning, doing its work, and the asynchronous task can, on the side, with no performance hit, invisibly populate a hidden div, with each spin/run of the main JavaScript thread. Once the asynchronous task completes, a callback function can be called to hide your preloader div and make the formerly empty div with the main content, visible.

**So - one approach to this** would be to have the preloading div by itself in a simple page. It will load fast and clean and immediately. Have an empty div below it, which will hold the big, complex content, populated by an ajax call, which is asynchronous.  **Then**, on the **DOMContentLoaded** event of the simple page, make an ajax call to bring down the rest of the page and load that in the empty div. Takes one line to set a "global" event listener for the built-in DOMContentLoaded event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

If you want to buy yourself even more time, you could get a timer (with setTimeout() or setInterval()) and give yourself a few more seconds after the ajax call completes, to guarantee everything is completely loaded and ready to display. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

FYI, here's a discussion on JavaScript's threading model: https://medium.com/@francesco_rizzi/javascript-main-thread-dissected-43c85fce7e23

See also here for a thread discussion: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Answer (score 1):

Put your preloader at the top of your document using inline styles. It will get loaded more quickly.

You should put this in your `header` and not actually directly inline, but here's an example of what I mean that doesn't rely on external resources.

eg.

```
<div id="loader-wrapper" style="width: 100%; z-index: 99998;
position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; height: 100%;
background-color: #fff;">
   <div id="loader"></div>
   <div class="loader-section section-left"></div>
   <div class="loader-section section-right"></div>
<div>
```

This will hide everything as soon as the page renders.

You could also hide *everything else* on the page by default, and then show it when you turn off the preloader.

Comment: Preloader is on top already. I have tried to hide everything and the result is an empty screen before the loader appears, but I still do not get rid of the 0.5 empty second.

Comment: @VincentTeyssier You shouldn't hide *everything* on the page, only the things that aren't the preloader. Also I said for you to put your styles ***inline***. I've added an example for you (see above).

Comment: yes that's what I've done, hidding the container, but not the loader. I've added inline style, the rest was already as you suggested. Still the same issue

Comment: Your problem, from what we can ascertain from your description, is that your external resources are too heavy, but it doesn't make sense that you can see the rest of your site's content if you've placed the above code on your site -- it will hide everything as soon as the page begins to render. Another thing you  might try is moving your external JS to the footer instead -- but I don't see why this should change anything.

Comment: yeah I agree with you, my external resources are too heavy.
I already have all my js at the end of the html. I have moved the jQuery plugin and the init js to the top and it looks like there's a little progress by doing so. I have studied my loading timeline and before starting to parse the html, it send get requests to all the jpg of the page (which are long to get) and to tinymce.js (beforeunload)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. By default, set the style= display:none to the div that contains the HTML content of the page, leaving the loader HTML This will hide the contents of the content on load.
2. Using jquery document onload, show the loader, and at the close of the loader activity, change the style of the div, to display:inline or display:block

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this and the result is an empty screen before the loader appears, but I still do not get rid of the 0.5 empty second.

It looks to me that it tries to build the dom structure before displaying the loader, despite it is at begining of html and js file

Comment: You can try to loading a loader gif on page load, and set the settimeinterval to 5 secs, after which the loader gif can be hidden and the content div can be shown. Hope this helps.

Comment: settimeinterval will not help as the issue is at the very begining of the loading, before the loader actually appears

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a loader div at the top of the `body` (let's call it `.loader`)
2. Set `display:none` to all the direct children of the body but not the `.loader` as long as the body is not `.loaded` yet.
3. The script will add the `.loaded` class when the page is ready then all the children will be shown and the `.loader` will be hidden.

And the code:

```js
$(function() {
  // simulate the heavy page loading
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('body').addClass('loaded');
  }, 1500);
});
```

```css
body:not(.loaded) > *:not(.loader) {
  display:none;  
}

body.loaded .loader {
  display:none; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- put it at the top of the body tag -->
<div class="loader">Loading</div>
<div class="entire_content">
  Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum   
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried it, but actually it is pretty much the same trick as previous answers, hiding the content except the loader. The problem is still that the loader is not built first and starts after 0.5s of loading.

Comment: How your `loder` looks like? is a `.gif` image? `css` preloader? `svg` maybe?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with this (Or refer me to a demo URL)? Maybe I will can help you with this.

Comment: impossible, too heavy to fiddle and there is no demo url as it manages sensible data and is secured under sessions.

Comment: I asked for a fiddle with only the loader. I apologize for not clear enoughץ

Comment: here is the tuto I followed : https://ihatetomatoes.net/create-css3-spinning-preloader/#comment-29848

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98713/discussion-between-mosh-feu-and-vincent-teyssier).