# How to display a pre-loader GIF as soon as a page is redirected to another one on the same website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, preloader

I am working on an app that does some heavy calculations on user uploaded datasets and would like to display a GIF as soon as the user is redirected from the 'uploads' page to the 'results' page.

The issue is that I am able to display the GIF but it doesn't appear immediately; the page is redirected, calculations are being performed on the backend (it can take up to 3 minutes), and the GIF appears only a few seconds before the content appears. Am I misunderstanding the concept or is the approach below incorrect?

**layout.html (parent template):**

```
<body>
   <div class="container">
      {% block content %}{% endblock %}
   </div>

   <script>$(document).ready(function () { 
   $(".preloader").fadeOut("slow");  
   });
   </script>
</body>
```

**results.html (child template):**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}

<h2>Your Results</h2>

{{ score_data | safe }}

<div class="preloader"></div>

{% endblock %}
```

**css:**

```
.preloader {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   z-index: 9999;
   background-image: url('../images/gifs/loader.gif');
   background-repeat: no-repeat; 
   background-color: #FFF;
   background-position: center;
}
```

Basically I would expect the GIF to show as soon as the uploads page is redirected to results page but the GIF appears minutes later when the results content is almost ready to display.

Any tips/help would be appreciated!

Comment: so the heavy part of the content is in the DOM . as is your preloader. thats why it only appears after the content loads. what you need to do..  on the backend set a switch when finished.. only show the preloader when it isnt finished and poll a json endpoint via ajax. similar issue here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34415765/preloader-div-doesnt-load-before-most-of-the-dom

Comment: Your page is rendering on the server and isn't sent to the client until your results are ready, hence your loader only shows once those results are ready and, therefore, only briefly. Have read up on asynchronous ajax calls or think about polling the server for the results if you want the paradigm you are trying to achieve to work...

Comment: why not simply serve the blank child template (with only the spinner within it) and later serve the results of your calculations - at which point you remove the spinner also?